# Declarate a dynamic array of pointers

Tags: c++

I have a class called "Cara" and I have this atribute in other class :
`Cara** caras;`. `caras` is a array of pointers to object of type "Cara".

I don't know how I can declare this attribute. Can you help me?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure what you're asking. If you could provide some code along with any errors or unexpected behavior that results, it would help.

Comment: If I do this: *cara= new Cara[numCaras]; For inicialize the atribute "caras", is fine?

Comment: Are you sure you want an "array of pointers-to-Caras" rather than a "pointer to an array of caras"?  Your declaration `Cara ** caras` indicates the former but  `new Cara[n]` gets you the latter. In any case, you cannot then assign that to `*caras` unless `caras` itself has been initialized. See answers below for how to allocate an array of Cara pointers—or better still, use the STL classes like `vector`.

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to tell what your problem is if you don't report a specific error of some sort. However, it may help you to know that you can declare a class:

```
class Cara; // this is called a "forward declaration"
```

and that allows you to refer to it:

```
class Bob { Cara ** caras; };
```

even before you have defined it:

```
class Cara { int foo; };
```

Comment: My problem is i don't know how initialize the atribute Cara** caras

Comment: In some method of `Bob`,  you might say `caras = new Cara* [20];` which makes space for 20 Cara pointers.  Then you might say `caras[0] = new Cara();` to initialize the first of those pointers—or of course you could just assign an already known pointer-to-a-Cara to that slot. And so on for the other slots.   Remember that, when you've finished using the objects, you must `delete` each of the `cara[i]` that you have allocated with `new`,  and finally `delete [] caras`,  otherwise you'll have memory leaks.

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to allocate an array of pointers to objects of type `Cara`, you can use:

```
Cara **caras = new Cara *[numElements];
```

If you then want to allocate the `Cara` objects themselves, you can use:

```
for(int i = 0; i < numElements; ++i)
    caras[i] = new Cara;
```

Comment: By the way, I agree with @ThomasMatthews that you should be using `std::vector` if you're already using C++.

Answer (score 1):

Prefer not to use arrays, but `std::vector`.

With `std::vector`:

```
class Cara;

std::vector<Cara *> my_vector_of_pointers;

//...
for (i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
{
  my_vector_of_pointers.push_back(new Cara);
}
```

If you must use arrays:

```
#define ARRAY_CAPACITY 10
Cara * my_array_of_pointers[ARRAY_CAPACITY];
```

As another note, prefer to use smart pointers rather than regular pointers.  Search the web for "boost smart_ptr" or "boost shared_ptr".

Comment: why not `const int ARRAY_CAPACITY = 10` instead of `#define` ?

Comment: @Mhd.Tahawi:  Sorry, old habit.  The `const int ARRAY_CAPACITY = 10` should also work.